# Why @JsonTypeInfo doesn't work as expected?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I try to serialize type info for my classes hierarchy but it seems that Jackson doesn't notice @JasonTypeInfo annotation. So to verify it I wrote extremely simple test and got the same result.
Jackson version 2.15.2

```
public class SimpleJsonTest
{
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test1(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.activateDefaultTyping(mapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator());
        List<Shape> shapes = List.of(new Shape(1), new Circle(10, 30));
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(shapes));
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "circle")
})
class Shape {
    int id;

    public Shape() {}
    public Shape(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape{
    int radius;

    public Circle(){}
    public Circle(int id, int radius) {
        super(id);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

As a result I got:

```
[["com.example.Shape",{"id":1}],["com.example.Circle",{"id":10,"radius":30}]]
```

without type property.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Looks interesting, it show `type` when we write single object like `System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Circle(10, 30)));`. And not work when it is a list.

Comment: Because of type erasure the `shapes` variable is effectively a `List<Object>`, so as far as Jackson is concerned the values in the array are `Object` values and not `Shape` values. So it doesn't use the `JsonTypeInfo` annotations on `Shape`. Meanwhile, because you've called `activateDefaultTyping` it wraps the serialised object in an array where thr first element is the actual object class name (e,g. "com.example.Shape").